# disabled BootstrapButton After submit MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I am trying to disable my button **after** submit (disable button for the user don't click when is loading) as bellow

### JS:

```
<script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button"/>
```

This code work very good : when I click my button is disable :), but my button doesn't work, its like disable before submit.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a somewhat built-in methodology to do this. It's for setting loading states on buttons, and not necessarily just for disabling in general, but it's actually better, in my opinion, as it gives some visual feedback to your user that something is actually happening.

```
<button type="button" data-loading-text="Submitting..." class="btn btn-primary">
  Submit
</button>

<script>
  $('[data-loading-text]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).button('loading');
  });
</script>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr3Rr/) for an example in action.

Comment: Thanks you is exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for too.... However... Once the "submission" is complete, how would you reset it?

Comment: @ChrisHammond: If this is a traditional form post, then the page will change, so the button goes away with it. If it's an AJAX request, then you just call `$('#myButton").button('reset')` in your AJAX callback.

Comment: Thanks.... I'm using "Ajax.BeginForm" and found the "OnComplete" event so added it to that and it worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button"/>
```

and use form submit event to disable button:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
        $(this).find("input:submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

Comment: your solutions work too, but im gonna use data-loading-text from bootstrap thanks you